# How to make vim AutoComplPop always highlight the first selection?

Tags: javascript, vim, autocomplete

I use the vim plugin AutoComplPop to auto complete my JavaScript code, here I meet a problem.

When I want a completion, I have to press the ↓ button, it's troublesome.

Can anyone tell me how to make the first selection highlighted, so that I don't have to press ↓ then press enter to complete my code.

Also, is there a method that I can select the selection of completion without the ↓?

Comment: What do you mean by "complement" here?

Comment: I use ACP too and the behavior you want is the behavior I get without setting any ACP-specific option and with `completeopt` set to nothing, set to the default value or set to my preferred value. And you can also use `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` to navigate the menu.

Comment: I second romainl; this is built into ACP, and should work like that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Use SuperTab! https://github.com/ervandew/supertab

Add this to your vimrc:

```
let g:SuperTabLongestHighlight = 1
```

From its help file:

<sup>Sets whether or not to pre-highlight the first match when completeopt has the
popup menu enabled and the 'longest' option as well. When enabled, *tab* will
kick off completion and pre-select the first entry in the popup menu, allowing
you to simply hit *enter* to use it.</sup>